# What's the maximum number of powered rails in a row that's useful?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm going through my rail network, replacing boosters with powered rails. However I'm finding that unlike boosters, which 'break' the laws of minecraft physics (by giving the cart much more momentum than its speed should allow), powered rails can't propel carts over very long distances, and it seems that even making a very long boost doesn't help this.

How should I cluster my powered rails for maximum efficiency? How many should I put at a time, both on flat, and inclined stretches?

#### Update

I've un-answered this question and added a bounty to reflect the changes in 1.6.

Comment: This is only an observation, but I think they are twice as powerful now.

Comment: @The yes notch doubled their power in 1.6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For inclines in **1.6** (tested), one powered rail at the bottom of a slope will boost a cart with a player in it up 6 blocks before needing another boost.

EDIT: TaviRider [has made another great video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7CyaCeS3fY) showing all the powered rail things in 1.6.

Comment: Will 2 rails at the bottom power you for 12?

Comment: Have not had chance to test, but since only the speed has been jacked up my assumption is it will take you about 8 or 9.

Comment: So... Powered rails *only* increase the minecart's speed, and not total momentum, as the original boosters did? Meaning you can't just do a one-for-one replacement of tracks, but have to go down the entire rail line putting in powered sections?

Comment: @Cyclops They increase the momentum to max+a little, instead of max+a lot.

Comment: @Communist Duck, I'm not sure what you mean by "max+a little" - carts *used* to have a really high momentum. I had a 12-track booster that would drive a cart around a fairly large circle (including uphill), and when I replaced it with 10 Powered tracks, the cart didn't get up the first hill.

Comment: @Cyclops Powered rail will increase the momentum to only a little over the maximum when there is enough, whereas no such limit exists for old boosters.

Comment: Dang, I was afraid of that. So, given that to replace a booster system requires Powered rails every 26 blocks, and every *two* blocks for slopes (*plus* a power source) - the net effect is a **major nerf** to boosting. Thanks, Notch...

Comment: Every 37. It was proven. :p

Answer (score 28):

To boost the cart speed from zero to maximum, you need 4 powered rails in sequence.

To maintain maximum speed you need one powered rail each 26 blocks (25 blocks of rail, 1 block of powered rail).

To maintain maximum speed on slopes, you need to power each second block on the slope.

Comment: I tested powered rails on slopes in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/how-often-is-a-powered-rail-required-to-keep-going-uphill/20430#20430) and found a powered rail every other track works fine (more specifically, every third is not enough).

Comment: @Kevin Thx for verification.

Answer (score 22):

All sorts of good related information:

[image: Powered Rail Chart]

Comment: "who disturbs our meditation, as a pebble disturbs the stillness of the pond?"  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8VD4JXUozM

Comment: a word of warning, the answer to this is most likely changing with 1.6, as per http://notch.tumblr.com/post/5775170768/the-changelist-for-1-6.

Comment: @Raven My cursor is poised over the bounty button for when that happens...

Comment: @Raven Dreamer - [powered rails increased by 12%](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/hkvrl/minecart_science_and_164_that_powered_rail_buff/)