# What's the minimum number of booster tracks needed to get up to full speed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the maximum number of powered rails in a row that's useful?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/whats-the-maximum-number-of-powered-rails-in-a-row-thats-useful)

I have been laying down a massive rail system over the last week or so, and the time has finally come to put in the booster tracks - I'm wondering what the minimum amount of track that is needed to get up to full speed?

I don't want to waste any more track than is needed, since I'm not willing to hack in any materials, and gold is in short supply.

As a follow up - is it better to use long strips of boosters, or broken up into smaller groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Minecraft wiki has a lot of info on [optimal booster usage](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail#Optimal_Use).

Boosting from rest to max speed requires 3 tracks in a row for v1.6 and 1 every 42 spaces to maintain it on straight, flat ground.

Comment: 42? I thought it was 37.