# How frequently should I place booster rails to maintain maximum speed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the maximum number of powered rails in a row that's useful?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/whats-the-maximum-number-of-powered-rails-in-a-row-thats-useful)

I want my minecarts to travel as quickly as possible, whether or not they are occupied.  Assuming everything is flat, what is the maximum distance between booster rails needed to maintain maximum speed?

Comment: See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/21438/336

Comment: pretty much exact duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24148/whats-the-minimum-number-of-booster-tracks-needed-to-get-up-to-full-speed

Comment: @Ender Not a duplicate.  That question asks how many are needed to initially boost the cart; this question asks how frequently they should be placed farther down the line.

Comment: @Maxpm: I stand corrected.