# How to make carts go up an incline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've made some tracks and a cart but I can't figure out how to make the cart "go." It kind of glides along slowly when I put it down on the track and hop in, but does not have enough momentum to even go up a 1 cube incline.

Comment: With this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwXTQHlACE8 (also, any other way of building enough momentum, be it boosters, gravity or powered minecarts)

Comment: @Yourdoom I'm not sure if by "booster" you meant "powered rails" or the side-by-side cart trick that increases speed.  If it's the latter, I hate to break the news to you that boosters have been identified as a bug and are going to be fixed with next week's 1.6 update.  Rail systems everywhere will suffer :)

Comment: Yeah I meant powered rails, never gotten boosters to work (haven't tried much which might be the reason though :p). Slimes still work though :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a short term solution, a [Powered Minecart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Minecart) is probably adequate if you're not going up severe inclines.

[image]

The extensive use of coal over long periods of time probably isn't worth it though.  If you are going to want to continue to use this setup for a long time, you should look into [powered rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail).  They're more expensive to create, but they also don't require any materials for continued usage.  If you go with powered rails, you will be interested to read this [previously asked question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/how-often-is-a-powered-rail-required-to-keep-going-uphill)

Comment: As I commented on the linked question, switches are a cheap and useful way to power the powered rails; you get to save your redstone for repeaters, wire and tracks, and the switch allows you to disable the booster without breaking a torch.

Answer (score 2):

The answer your looking for, other than a powered mine cart, is a [powered rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail).

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Minecart