# How far apart do I need powered rail to get up a 1 block ledge and maintain speed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that to maintain 8m/s (7.9something) on flat ground I have 37 rails between powered rails.

What distance do I need to maintain the same speed if there is a 1 block ledge between powered rails?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/how-often-is-a-powered-rail-required-to-keep-going-uphill?rq=1

Answer (score 17):

Ok I think I figured it out.

On the Minecraft wiki for Minecarts under Loss of Speed says

> One unit of kinetic energy could be defined as the energy gained by a cart going down a one block slope, and lost by a cart when it goes up a one block slope.

Later it says

> ...an initial height of 60 blocks will result in a final height of 40 blocks, a loss of 20 units of potential energy. But if 20 sections of flat track are inserted between the slopes, the final height will be 35. This implies that one unit of energy is lost for every 4 sections of horizontal track traveled...

So to get the same result you need to bring the powered rail 4 blocks closer i.e. 33 blocks between powered rails with a ledge in between.

This can be extended for any number of ledges by subtracting (ledges x 4) from 37.

Hope this helps anyone else who wonders.

Comment: Nice post and answer. Just a small thing: I think you should either talk about the tracks in between powered rails (37) or the repetition rate of powered rails (1 per every 38). In fact, your answer uses the rate but says otherwise (small mistake, but noteworthy).

Comment: The actual relation seems considerably more complex. Following your approach,  H = 37-(4 x H) gives H=7.4; a powered rail every 7 blocks should sustain uphill climb indefinitely when approached at max speed. Meanwhile, a powered rail every 3 blocks is not sustainable, the cart slowing down to a crawl and eventually reversing; only 4 powered rails per 10 blocks maintain the uphill speed.