# How frequent do you have to use powered rails uphill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How frequent do I have to place powered rails to keep climbing at **full speed**?

Some people say that you only have to use the same amount from powered and non powered, but you can do like 3 powered and 3 unpowered. This is not true, I tried that out. The best way seems to be switching between powered and non-powered (one powered, one non-powered, one powered, ...), which brings a big waste of redstone torches with it. Any other ideas? I didn't test it enough to prove it.

This is NOT the same question as [this one here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/how-often-is-a-powered-rail-required-to-keep-going-uphill). I ask specifically for full speed and not "minimum of powered rails/maintain reasonable speed".

Comment: A question being outdated isn't a reason to ask it again.  It's a reason to bounty it, if the answers are out of date.

Comment: The linked question is about the minimum requirement to climb. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio of normal rails to powered rails depends on the speed the minecart is already moving. For the sake of the question, however I am going to assume that the minecart is starting and going immediately uphill in which case (as of 1.9):

`+`: powered rail
`-`: normal rail
`\`: repeat

- If you press <kbd>w</kbd> the whole way: `+--+--+--\`
- If you **don't** press <kbd>w</kbd> the whole way: `+-+--+-+--\`

This is assuming that you are transporting a player, otherwise the answer is completely different.

P.S. Yes, this is for maximum speed.

Comment: Very nice answer. Do you have sources for this or did you try this out by yourself?

Comment: I did have to try this one out myself because there didn't seem to be anyone who had tried it out before me.